# How can we get sorted result of similar interest SXA query using tags

Tags: sxa-search, taxonomy

I want to fetch people with similar interests based on common taxonomy tags.

I am following the Sitecore documentation section "Add a query item that uses a token" mentioned here:

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/sxa/19/sitecore-experience-accelerator/walkthrough--using-a-query-to-render-items.html

I have written a query and am getting the expected result but I don't find any way to get the sorted result.

[image]

e.g. I want to fetch people result order by updated date. I have tried the sort option using `sort:<field-name> | value` but did not help.

Request your support to achieve the sorted result.

Thanks,
Hari

Answer (score 0):

Use `order by` clause in your query:

`query:$home//*[contains(@@templateid,'{templateid}') and (contains(@@taxonomyfield,'{taxonomytag}'))] order by @@updated desc`

Comment: Hi Biswajit, Thanks for your inputs. I just tried putting your suggested query like custom:query|$home//*[contains(@@templateid,'{342696b0-2b67-406f-8e49-c7acc7894741}')] order by @@__updated desc  in the Sitecore but did not get any result. I want to use  **sxa:TaggedWithAtLeastOneTagFromCurrentPage|SxaTags** in the query and get the result with sorting order.

Answer (score 0):

To Sort the results by *updated date*, you will need to use `sort:__updated` in the query builder dialog box. Your query should look like below:
Make sure you have `Sitecore_sxa_master_index` rebuilt successfully.

```
+location:{685C0CDE-E82D-44AB-A88E-7E6000F2A1FB};template:{41FD7D9F-DF8B-404F-8FB2-66BF8777D381};sort:__updated
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Raman, Thanks for your inputs. I have tried your suggestions but am getting error as _Object reference not set to an instance of object at @Html.RenderingVariants().RenderVariant(variantField, Model.Item, Model.RenderingWebEditingParams, Model) in file ~\Views\Variants\Page Content.cshtml _  I think in normal case as you suggested sorting works but if I am using **sxa:TaggedWithAtLeastOneTagFromCurrentPage|SxaTags**  along with sort in build query then it does not bring any result . What could I try pls?

Comment: I am able to get the sorted result  with usage of solr index field ___smallupdateddate_tdt_ then the Query looks like **+template:{342696b0-2b67-406f-8e49-c7acc7894741};+sxa:TaggedWithAtLeastOneTagFromCurrentPage|SxaTags;sort:__smallupdateddate_tdt[desc]**   Sitecore __updated field is stored in the solr index as __smallupdateddate_tdt field

Comment: thanks @HariWaghamare. I just checked i was getting results with sxa:TaggedWithAtLeastOneTagFromCurrentPage|SxaTags as well. Glad that you are able to resolve with __smallupdateddate_tdt